# Encrypt all disk and decrypt it depending on the sytem hardware

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, license, licensing

Is there any tool that can encrypt a whole disk and use a decrypt key based on the hardware of the machine?

My goal is to create anti-copy OS that can only run on a specific machine, if i change the disk to a machine that is identical, same model/vendor, it wouldn't work.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to re-write TrueCrypt into something that checks the hardware ID or MAC address (or whatever other hardware you wanted to test) and attempt to use the hardware ID (or combination thereof) as the key to encrypt and decrypt.. you probably can. Whether there is an existing software that does exactly as you want, I don't know.

Comment: Besides MAC i can't find any unique hardware ID. I am using ALIX2d13 single board PC, where dmidecode is not supported, and other tools like lspci etc don't retrieve me any useful hardware unique ID. If someone know any tool that can retrieve me serial numbers, i appreciate.